# ClojureScript Browser Repl using script Element in head

Tags: google-closure-compiler, clojurescript, google-closure-library

I am (still) new to ClojureScript an understand the browser repl makes use of an iframe. I am trying to introduce the ClojureScript application in an existing app and it would be convenient to add the generated JavaScript to in the head of the document. Doing so unfortunately breaks `clojure.browser.repl/connect` trying to add the iframe to an `undefined` parent element in `goog.net.xpc.CrossPageChannel.prototype.createPeerIframe`.

Is there a reasonable approach to make the compiled JavaScript work when you put the `script` element in the `head` of the document?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your problem? [Austin](https://github.com/cemerick/austin) browser REPL [example](https://github.com/cemerick/austin/tree/master/browser-connected-repl-sample) works great. In `index.html` single `script` tag is child of the `head` tag.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for pointing it out. I started working trough  https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs and those pages (e.g. ``shopping-dbg.html``) break in ``connect`` when you move the script element in the head.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in https://github.com/tomjakubowski/weasel as an alternative for your browser repl needs.  Instead of using iframes, it uses WebSockets.  You shouldn't have to worry about script element placement as long as dependencies are run in order.